# Is W and X countable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set X of all sequences $x_n$ of natural numbers.
Let $Y=\{x_n\in X: x_n=0\text{ for infinitely many }n\}$,
$W=\{x_n\in X: x_n\neq0\text{ for finitely many }n\}$, which of the above sets are countable.

My first question is ,since X contains $0$ for infinetely many n, can I say X contains non zero elements for only finitely many n,i.e.is it same as W?

For Z, I will first need to choose finite nth positions, for which corresponding value is non zero,,so rest places will be zero. Then for each such case, the possible sequences is the subset of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\times..\times0\times.\times{\mathbb{N}}$, which is countable. and entire Z is contained in unions of such cartesian product so is countable.

But I believe my logic is correct provided the non zero nth position  is fixed. am I correct?..

thabks in advance!

Comment: You can easily encode any $0$-$1$-sequence (of which there are uncountably many) in a sequence in $Y\cap W$ by setting one element to $0$, the next element to $1$, the next element to the next value in your sequence and then repeat.

Comment: $Y$ contains the set of all sequences $(x_n) \in \mathbb N ^ \mathbb N$ such that $x_{2n}=0$ and $x_{2n+1} \neq 0$. The cardinality of the latter is $ |\mathbb N ^ \mathbb N|$. On the other hand, $|W|= |\cup_{n \ge1} \mathbb N^n| $ which is ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer:

**Question 1**:
$$x_n = \begin{cases} 0, &n\text{ even} \\ 1, &n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$$
Is non-zero for infinitely many $n$. But it is also $0$ for infinitely many $n$. Thus giving you a counter example.

Now, i haven't really found a second question. But the key to solving the problem comes from the fact that sequences in $W$ have only finitely many non-zero elements, meaning:

> For every $w_n \in W$, you can find $N_w \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $w_n = 0$ for $n \geq N_w$.

I won't completely solve the problem for you (because this looks like Homework), but understanding the example and my statement (in particular the role of $N_w$), will lead you to the solution for $W$ and $X$.